# Removing comma from number format with unique XSLT coding

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

With the example below, the XSLT is doing a few things, it is grouping by column 1 and column2, if it is the same, then it will group the column 3 amount. As well, within the PayAmount tags, it is reversing negative (-) number into a positive and vice versa.  What I am having troubles with is writing logic to remove the comma (,) from column 3 in the output.

**Below is my XSLT Code**

```
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:for-each select="row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key(''rows'', concat(column1, ''||'', column2)))]">
      </Record>
          <Detail>
            <Amount>
              <xsl:variable name="mySum">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key(''rows'', concat(column1, ''||'', column2))/column3)" />
              </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(($mySum * ($mySum &gt;= 0) - $mySum * not($mySum &gt;= 0)),'','','''')" />
            </Amount>
          </Detail>
        </Record>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried the following logic, but the comma remains in the output:

```
-    <xsl:value-of select="translate(($mySum * ($mySum &gt;= 0) - $mySum * not($mySum &gt;= 0)),'','', '''')" />
-    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($mySum * ($mySum &gt;= 0) - $mySum * not($mySum &gt;= 0),'#,##0.00')" />
-    <xsl:value-of select="translate(sum(key(''rows'', concat(column1, ''||'', column2))/column3),'','','''')" />
```

**Below is a sample data in XML:**

```
  <data>
    <row>
        <column1>200040</column1>
        <column2>Auto</column2>
        <column3>-500.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200040</column1>
        <column2>Auto</column2>
        <column3>-5,000.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200040</column1>
        <column2>Auto</column2>
        <column3>-1,000.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200040</column1>
        <column2>Auto</column2>
        <column3>300.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200040</column1>
        <column2>Auto</column2>
        <column3>-4,000.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200041</column1>
        <column2>Bike</column2>
        <column3>-1,700.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200041</column1>
        <column2>Bike</column2>
        <column3>-1,000.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200041</column1>
        <column2>Bike</column2>
        <column3>800.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200045</column1>
        <column2>Bus</column2>
        <column3>200.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200045</column1>
        <column2>Bus</column2>
        <column3>-10,000.00</column3>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>200045</column1>
        <column2>Bus</column2>
        <column3>5,000.00</column3>
    </row>
    </data>
```

**The output I would like to achieve after running the XSLT is**

200040 |     Auto          | 10200.00

200041 |     Bike          | 1900.00

200045 |     Bus           | 4800.00

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please explain how you arrive from `(-500.00, -5,000.00, -1,000.00, 300.00, -4,000.00)` to 2200.00.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, apologies my calculation was not correct. It should be 10200.00. I have corrected it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value that contains a comma is not a number and cannot be summed. You need to remove the commas **before** you attempt to sum the values.

Here's a simplified example:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT node-set()**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="a" match="amount" use="@key"/>

<xsl:template match="data">
    <!-- first pass: convert amounts to numbers -->
    <xsl:variable name="amounts">
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <amount key="{concat(column1, '|', column2)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(column3, ',', '')"/>
            </amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <Output>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($amounts)/amount[generate-id() = generate-id(key('a', @key))]">
            <Record>
                <Detail1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@key, '|')"/>
                </Detail1>
                <Detail2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@key, '|')"/>
                </Detail2>
                <xsl:variable name="sum" select="sum(key('a', @key))"/>
                <Amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($sum, '0.00')"/>
                </Amount>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Output>
  <Record>
    <Detail1>200040</Detail1>
    <Detail2>Auto</Detail2>
    <Amount>-10200.00</Amount>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Detail1>200041</Detail1>
    <Detail2>Bike</Detail2>
    <Amount>-1900.00</Amount>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Detail1>200045</Detail1>
    <Detail2>Bus</Detail2>
    <Amount>-4800.00</Amount>
  </Record>
</Output>
```

---

To reverse negative amounts to positive (and vice versa), you could simply change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($sum, '0.00')"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(-$sum, '0.00')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k for the quick help/solution to this!